# sklearn.manifold.TSNE fit_transform actually return something on empty numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

Why does `tsne.fit_transform([[]])` actually returns something?

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import numpy

tsne = TSNE(n_components=2,
    early_exaggeration=4.0,
    learning_rate=1000.0,
    metric='euclidean',
    init='random',
    random_state=42)

# returns [[  4.96714153e-05  -1.38264301e-05]]
print tsne.fit_transform(numpy.array([[]]))
```

But changing `init` from `random` to `pca` raises exception: `ValueError: failed to create intent(cache|hide)|optional array-- must have defined dimensions but got (0,)`.

Comment: That's a bug. I reported it here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4615

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `init='random'` the embedding `X_embedded` [gets initialized to `None`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/cda6438253c6bc54bc272a528155ddd0d17e9f59/sklearn/manifold/t_sne.py#L454) and later with random weights, this is the relevant code:

**[`scikit-learn/sklearn/manifold/t_sne.py`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/cda6438253c6bc54bc272a528155ddd0d17e9f59/sklearn/manifold/t_sne.py#L474)**

```
if X_embedded is None:
    # Initialize embedding randomly
    X_embedded = 1e-4 * random_state.randn(n_samples, self.n_components)
```

With `init='pca'` the embedding gets initialized via a PCA transformation:

```
if self.init == 'pca':
    pca = RandomizedPCA(n_components=self.n_components,
                            random_state=random_state)
    X_embedded = pca.fit_transform(X)
```

This fails for empty arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I meant what characteristics of PCA method would not accept empty numpy array, not specific where in the sklearn the code breaks. After reading http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_pca_step_by_step.html, I'm going to try formulating a checklist on what kind of dataset is best in each approach.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it, for me this is an implementation issue. Do you want to know what would be the meaning/interpretation of applying PCA to a null vector?

Comment: Yes, understanding how PCA transform a dataset helps me to understand why PCA cannot operate on null vector while randomize algorithm can. My question also evolves to what kind of dataset works better with PCA, like this link http://blog.explainmydata.com/2012/07/should-you-apply-pca-to-your-data.html.

Comment: I doesn't make sense in any case to apply dimensionality reduction methods to a null vector, it is just that in the random case because of the way the scikit guys implemented the `TSNE ` algorithm, it returns something, but it would have been more correct to raise an error and be explicit about it.

Comment: For questions not related to code and the implementation I recommend you go to [Cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Agreed. Based on what I've read so far, it has nothing to do how PCA transforms the dataset but rather how scikit implements it. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, that is a bug. ;) TSNE.fit_transform should definitely raise an error here. You should never be able to transform nothing to anything. You can report bugs in sklearn here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues . I will do that now.

Comment: By the way, [[]] is not the null vector. [[0]] would be a null vector. [[]] means there is no data at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. It has been fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/d16e9eeb1b7bac18dcfd99ed3c8470c7d05eb3f3) and should be included since release 0.16.x.

You can install the current sklearn for example version with pip:

```
(sudo) pip install scikit-learn
```

Now, sklearn will raise an error:

```
In [1]: from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

In [2]: TSNE().fit_transform([[]])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-39cfca09a0bd> in <module>()
----> 1 TSNE().fit_transform([[]])

...

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features)
    365             raise ValueError("Found array with %d feature(s) (shape=%s) while"
    366                              " a minimum of %d is required."
--> 367                              % (n_features, shape_repr, ensure_min_features))
    368     return array
    369 

ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(1, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```